# Projects SAVED as vs12 .suo files

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I recently upgraded from windows 8.1 to 8.1 pro.(which i done because, 8.1 couldn't run the emulator  for VS 2013 as it could not access the Hyper V) But since I've done that, all of my saved projects are now of type .suo, and when I try to open them on VS 2013 I get binary code. If I open VS and create a new project it works fine. Any help regarding how I can change it back, would be Great

Answer (score 2):

Those are [Solution User Options files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165909.aspx). Your sln file should still be there and still be open-able.

> The solution user options (.suo) file contains per-user solution
>   options. This file should not be checked in to source code control.
>
> The .suo file is a structured storage, or compound, file stored in a
>   binary format. You save user information into streams with the name of
>   the stream being the key that will be used to identify the information
>   in the .suo file. The solution user options file is used to store user
>   preference settings, and is created automatically when Visual Studio
>   saves a solution.

Comment: Feel free to hit the Checkbox to accept the answer :D

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is correct. Just to help you, in Windows Explorer in Windows 7, go to Windows Explorer, menu Tools, Folder Options, select the Tab View and in Advanced Options uncheck the option that hides the extensions for known file types.

I don't have Windows 8/8.1 but as I remember you have a "View" menu and on the right side a button called Options. There you have almost the same options you have in Win7.

Next go to the folder where you found the ".suo" file and you should have a ".sln" file.